# ImportError: cannot import name 'osc' from 'kivy.lib'

Tags: python, kivy

My kivy application keeps crashing on android when trying to `import osc from kivy.lib` with the following error:

```py
ImportError: cannot import name 'osc' from 'kivy.lib'
```

I've already included oscpy as a requirement in my buildozer.spec file, please how may I fix this?

Comment: what command are you using to import. Please update the code for us to be able to answer your query

Comment: from kivy.lib import osc

Comment: Do you know any other way for my main file to communicate with my background service on android?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but my quick search on this topic lead me to the information that it was discontinued and replaced by kivy/oscpy

Here's the GibHub repository for your reference
https://github.com/kivy/oscpy

Info sourced from:
https://github.com/tshirtman/kivy_service_osc/issues/2